# Making HTML5 videos stored on AWS S3 **difficult** to download (because I cant make it impossible)

Tags: html, video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building a website that hosts video's stored on AWS's S3 service. The videos are played thru a HTML5 player we have built.

Ive just been asked to make sure "nobody can steal our video's".

Now I know that if you really don't want something stolen, don't put it up on the internet. However I just need to secure these videos as good as possible, the videos need to at the very least resist someone going thru the source code and trying to download them manually.

One option available to me is to completely rebuild the video player in flash. This is not ideal, for several reasons, notably because I would also then have to build an App for mobile devices to be able to view this site.

So I am looking for other options.

I have heard about using a token to make the file available only during certain times.

I have heard of using a separate file to serve the videos that sits between the HTML5 page and the video file.

I am also having a look at IAM, the Secure AWS Access Control, in the hopes AWS can solve this problem for me.

Can anyone here recommend any of these options? Or perhaps suggest other options available to me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to make videos that are difficult to "copy" your ultimate solution will be streaming with DRM.

At the moment, this excludes using HTML5. There are plans to put in place DRM extensions for HTML5 video, but nothing is final yet.

You can make a file private on s3, and provide access via a signed link. This link will be valid for a time that you choose. But you can still copy the file as long as you have access to it.